# Tab App Position Value On Fan Pages Is No Longer Used/Working On Facebook New Layout

Tags: facebook

On fan pages, tab apps used to be displayed on the left side of the page, and their order was controlled by the "position" value they have (which is described on the api). On the new Facebook layout for profiles, tab applications are now displayed at the top of the profile, with the description, the profile pic, etc. as "favorites".

They're displayed as a list of icons and only a handful of them are visible at the time, and, the position value has no longer any effect on the order, no matter how you set it with the api, the apps do not change their order now.

Does anyone know how to change the order of the apps on the new layout for a fan page by calling the javascript api? (I know how to do it on the Facebook ui, not interested in that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same thing today, and this seems to be [a documented bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/258592880887783). Current status, as per the 21st of March 2012, is assigned, so there's hope yet.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen in the videos and blogs about the new timeline layout for pages, it appears Facebook has been removing some of the focus from the app tabs, over to the timeline view itself.  The choices of what order the "tabs" are shown in on the new timeline is now controlled by an admin directly interacting with the Facebook UI, rather than programmatically via the API.